# Confusion with laser diode parameters and I/V curves from its datasheets

Tags: laser-diode

I have [this](https://pdfhost.io/v/%7EkvXX2RXe_Pigtailed_Laser_Diode) fiber coupled laser diode. And its specs given as:

[image]

But the datasheet also says it used [this](https://pdfhost.io/v/eT%7Ei.It2H_FT) particular diode. And the specs are given as:

[image]

And the I/V/P curves:

[image]

The thing is the first fiber coupled module supposed to be using the TO packaged diode in the second link. But their nominal powers do not match. The first one says its max optical power is 60mW and the second one says 140 mW.

Now I want to use this fiber coupled diode for 50mW optical output in continuous mode(not pulsed). I have a constant current source. What should be the current through the laser diode and its forward voltage drop for 50mW optical output?

Comment: are you certain that the LED is the correct one? ... the curves do not match the first table ... the curve shows 50 mW output at ~170 mA and ~1.05 V

Comment: The datasheet says so https://pdfhost.io/v/~kvXX2RXe_Pigtailed_Laser_Diode It says it is using FPL1055TP if you look at the table.

Comment: yes, it says that ... maybe a typo ... maybe there is a power loss at the fiber interface ... you could try to contact the manufacturer for clarification

Answer (score 1):

The diode specs a minimum cw power of 140mW at a current Icw of 400mA. This is a performance guarantee, not a restriction. The diode will easily deliver 50mW continuously.

From the PVI chart, 50mW will require 140ish mA. The data sheet puts the typical current at 200mA.

The voltage drop will be approximately 1V from the chart.

The specs on the pigtail are reduced. The packaging appears to have a lower thermal conductivity than a good heat sink would have. The diode has robust flange for attaching to a good heat sink for higher power applications.

There may be other reasons to restrict the specifications, such as optical matching to the fibre.